# Vim: use globpath to obtain different filetypes

Tags: vim, glob

I have three files in my `Desktop`: `foo.py`, `foo.tex` and `foo.pdf`. I want to use the `globpath()` function to obtain the full path of the `python` and `tex` files but not the `pdf` file. I know I can do

```
:echo globpath('C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop', 'foo.tex')
```

or

```
:echo globpath('C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop', 'foo.py')
```

to obtain either the tex or the python full path. How do I obtain the full path of both files? i.e I'm looking for something like

```
:echo globpath('C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop', 'foo.(tex|py)')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `glob[path]()` functions only support a limited set of `:help wildcards`. You cannot do alternation like with regular expressions. Instead, just invoke the function multiple times and concatenate the results:

```
:echo globpath('C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop', 'foo.tex') . globpath('C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop', 'foo.py')
```

Recent Vim versions support the `, {list}` flag, with which you can make `globpath()` return Lists (which are concatenated with `+` instead of `.`).

---

Note that your example without actual wildcards is stupid; if you just need to transform a filespec into absolute form, you better use `fnamemodify(path, ':p')`.